TestNG parameter values are not updated for multi suites run when each suite has different values for the same parameter
TestRunner.java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> platformVersions = new ArrayList<>(){{add("14.0");add("11.0")}};
    for (String platformVersion: platformVersions) {
        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName(configuration.getPlatform() + " " + platformVersion);
        XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
        test.setName("Fragmentation run for : " + suite.getName());
        List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<>();
        XmlClass xmlClass1 = new XmlClass("io.demo.ClassOne");
        XmlClass xmlClass2 = new XmlClass(""io.demo.ClassTwo"")
        classes.add(xmlClass);
        test.setXmlClasses(classes);
        test.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.METHODS);
        suite.setThreadCount(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("threadcount", "5")));
        suite.setIncludedGroups(Arrays.asList(System.getProperty("groups").split(",")));
        suite.setParameters(Map.of("platformVersion", platformVersion));
        suites.add(suite);
    }
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.setParallel(XmlSuite.ParallelMode.NONE);
    testng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    testng.run();
}

BaseTest.java
@
BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters(value = "platformVersion")
    public void initSuite(ITestContext context, @Optional String platformVersion) {
        if (Objects.isNull(platformVersion) || (!platformVersion.isEmpty() && !platformVersion.isBlank())) // Here I am only getting platformVersion 14 for both the suites.
            System.out.println("platformVersion: " + platformVersion);
        else
            System.out.println("Platform version not provided");

    }

TestClass.java extending BaseTest.java
    @Test
public void test1(){
    System.out.println("This is test 1");
}

@Test
public void test2(){
    System.out.println("This is test 2");
}

In the @BeforeSuite method, it should give two different values for two suites but it is giving only one value for both suites.
I need clarification on this. Is this something expected or is it a bug in TestNG?
I am using TestNG 7.5.1

Your sample doesn't seem to be complete. So I went ahead and created a complete sample using TestNG 7.5.1 and it works fine.
Note: The latest released version of TestNG as of today is 7.10.2. Please upgrade (You will also need to use JDK11)
Test class looks like below
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestCaseA {
    @BeforeSuite
    @Parameters("platform")
    public void beforeSuite(String platform) {
        ITestResult itr = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
        System.err.println("Suite: " + itr.getTestContext().getSuite().getName() + ", platform: " + platform);
    }

    @Test
    public void testA() {
    }
}

Test runner looks like below:
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> platforms = List.of("ios", "android", "windows");
        for (String platform : platforms) {
            XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
            suite.setName("suite_" + platform);
            suite.setVerbose(2);
            suite.setParameters(Map.of("platform", platform));
            XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
            test.setName("test_" + platform);
            test.setClasses(List.of(new XmlClass(TestCaseA.class.getCanonicalName())));
            System.err.println(suite.toXml());
            suites.add(suite);
        }
        tng.setVerbose(2);
        tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
        tng.run();
    }
}

Execution output looks like below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite_ios" verbose="2">
  <parameter name="platform" value="ios"/>
  <test thread-count="5" name="test_ios" verbose="2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.so.qn78554630.TestCaseA"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- test_ios -->
</suite> <!-- suite_ios -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite_android" verbose="2">
  <parameter name="platform" value="android"/>
  <test thread-count="5" name="test_android" verbose="2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.so.qn78554630.TestCaseA"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- test_android -->
</suite> <!-- suite_android -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suite_windows" verbose="2">
  <parameter name="platform" value="windows"/>
  <test thread-count="5" name="test_windows" verbose="2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.so.qn78554630.TestCaseA"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- test_windows -->
</suite> <!-- suite_windows -->

...
... TestNG 7.5.1 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

Suite: suite_ios, platform: ios
PASSED: testA

===============================================
    test_ios
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
suite_ios
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

PASSED: testA

===============================================
    test_android
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
suite_android
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

PASSED: testA

===============================================
    test_windows
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Suite: suite_android, platform: android
Suite: suite_windows, platform: windows

===============================================
suite_windows
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0

